# Authorisation failure Connecting to TFS from Eclipse in Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, ubuntu, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I am using Eclipse Juno (Linux) and added TFS plug-in for Eclipse. Server URL `https://******ftware.visualstudio.com` and added username and password. This is my Microsoft Live ID which got access to Visual Studio online, but it gives an error message `Authorization failure connecting to https://******ftware.visualstudio.com` using this username and password.

Username and password works well when connecting from browser. Not sure what is going on.

This plug-in works well on a Windows machine.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I see a distinct lack of screenshot.

Comment: sorry i couln't attach images due to some problems

Answer (score 2):

You may need to use the "alternate credentials" that does not rely on an MSA (Live ID). In the web access you can click on your name in the top right. There should be a settings drop down that lets you enable and set the alternate credentials for Linux.

https://binary-stuff.com/post/how-to-enable-alternate-credentials-in-visual-studio-online-vso

Comment: Omg ... why is this not on by default or at least part of the official documentation! Thanks @MRHinsh .. btw. I provided feedback at https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/setup/connect-to-visual-studio-team-services to get this added to the docs at least.